# How to pass array in Sweet Alert 2 Promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, sweetalert2

I'm using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) to display forms which is working just great, however I have recently run into a problem that I am unable to solve and I have already wasted days trying to find a solution on Google.

I'm building a form dynamically with PHP that is loaded by Sweet Alert. The form contains multiple check-boxes with the same name/id. I have 3 sets of multiple check-boxes and because its a dynamic form I don't know how many check-boxes will be in each set.

The Check-box sets are named **invoice_details**, **invoice_hours** and **invoice_materials**. Each set might have no check-boxes or they might have ten or more. But each set of check-boxes have the same name, so invoice_details set are all named invoice_details.

**How can I get the results into an array for each group of check-boxes and pass them to the promise so I can process the form in a php page?**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // SCRIPT TO ADD INVOICE

    //Warning Message with function
    $(document).on('click', '#addinvoice', function(){
        swal({
    title: 'Generate New Invoice',
    html: '<?php echo tm_generate_invoice_form( $post->ID ) ?>',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
    buttonsStyling: true,
    confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg',
    cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-lg',
    preConfirm: function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      resolve([
        $('#invoice_number').val(),
        $('#invoice_details').val(),
        $('#invoice_hours').val(),
        $('#invoice_materials').val(),
        $('#invoice_custom_message').val(),
        $('#jobid').val(),
        $('#tm_add_invoice').val()
      ])
    })
  }
}).then(function(result){
            swal(
                "Invoice Created!",
                "Invoice now ready to be sent to customer.",
                "success"
            );
            $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>',
            data: {
                action: 'tm_add_invoice',
                invoice_number: result[0],
                invoice_details: result[1][0],
                invoice_hours: result[2][0],
                invoice_materials: result[3][0],
                invoice_custom_message: result[4],
                jobid: result[5],
                tm_add_invoice: result[6]
            },
            success: function(data){

                $('#invoices').html(data);

            },
            error: function(e){
                 alert("error " + e);
                 console.log(e);
            }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If `swal()` is thenable, why is the second `swal()` not then'd?

Comment: Two questions: 
(1) The form-building php - is it yours to modify?

(2) You say "I don't know how many check-boxes will be in each set" and "the check-box names are `invoice_details`, `invoice_hours` and `invoice_materials`". 
but it's not clear; does each set include those three checkboxes, or is there an `invoice_details` set, an `invoice_hours` set and an `invoice_materials` set?

Comment: Thanks for the response Roamer, yes the form building php is mine to modify. There is an invoice_details set, an invoice_hours set and an invoice_materials set. but a set might have no check boxes or it might have ten or more...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. One more question: on the server-side, are you interested in unchecked checkboxes? The reason I ask is that it's extremely simple to send data reflecting checked checkboxes but needs some artificial contrivance to include unchecked checkboxes.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter about unchecked boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget ids. Build the form with `name` attributes of the format `name="xxx[]"`.

For example :

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input name="invoice_number" value="invoice_no_000" /><br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_details[]" value="abc" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_details[]" value="bcd" /><br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_hours[]" value="cde" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_hours[]" value="def" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_hours[]" value="efg" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_hours[]" value="fgh" /><br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_materials[]" value="ghi" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_materials[]" value="hij" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_materials[]" value="ijk" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_materials[]" value="jkl" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_materials[]" value="klm" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_materials[]" value="lmn" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_materials[]" value="mno" /><br/>
    <br/>
    <!-- other fields as necessary -->
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

*Elements within each set need not necessarily be adjacent. Interleaved elements will serialize in the same way.*

Now you can simply serialize the form with jQuery's [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

```
'preConfirm': function () {
    return Promise.resolve($('#myForm').serialize());
}
```

As the documentation says :

> Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox") are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements is not serialized.

So, depending on which checkboxes are checked, the resultant serialization (with added line breaks) might be :

```
invoice_number%5B%5D=invoice_no_000&
invoice_details%5B%5D=bcd&
invoice_hours%5B%5D=cde&
invoice_hours%5B%5D=fgh&
invoice_materials%5B%5D=hij&
invoice_materials%5B%5D=jkl&
invoice_materials%5B%5D=klm&
invoice_materials%5B%5D=lmn
```

And server-side, PHP will see the data as :

- $_POST['invoice_number'] : 'invoice_no_000'
- $_POST['invoice_details'] : ['bcd']
- $_POST['invoice_hours'] : ['cde', 'fgh']
- $_POST['invoice_materials'] : ['hij', 'jkl', 'klm', 'lmn']

I suspect this is what is required.

Answer (score 0):

The following code combines names and ids as well as php POST request in the sweetalert2 popup.

Add the necessary code in the html field:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input name="invoice_number" value="invoice_no_000" /><br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_details[]" value="abc" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_details[]" value="bcd" /><br/>
    <br/>
</form>
<input id="datepicker-checkin" name="checkin-date" value="7-09-2020">' 
<input id="datepicker-checkout" name="checkout-date" value="9-09-2020">'
```

do a php POST request

```
preConfirm: () => {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "myfile.php",
        data: {
            checkin: document.getElementById('datepicker-checkin').value,
            checkout: document.getElementById('datepicker-checkout').value,
            invoices_data: $('#myForm').serialize(), //invoices_data contains every "name" data from the myForm form
        },
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        }
    });
}
```

Because the `.serialize` jQuery function converts the data into a string, all you have to do in the php file to handle the form parameters is use `parse_str`:

```
$searcharray = array();
parse_str($_POST['invoices_data'], $searcharray);

//save the other data from the request
$checkin = $_POST['checkin'];
$checkout = $_POST['checkout'];
...
```